# Solve for $x$, $3^{x^2} \lt 9^x$

Tags: inequality, monotone-functions

$3^{x^2} < 9^x$

According to my book the solution is $x>0 \land x < 2$ so I assume this is a quadratic equation.

Therefore, I need to have $variable^2+variable+ \not variable$.

But I don't know what *variable*  is in this case.

I have:

$3^{x^2}$

$9^x = (3^2)^x = 3^{2x}$

and so

$3^{x^2}-3^{x2}<0$

So I think that *variable* should be $3^x$, so that in:
$$ax^2 + bx +c,$$
$$a = 1$$
$$b = ???$$
$$c = 0$$

But I don't know what b should be in this case...

Am I thinking right? How do I solve this?

Comment: Since $3^{x^2}<3^{2x}$ you can alternatively solve $x^2 < 2x$ by using a logarithm to base $3$.

Answer (score 5):

You can use that $3^x$ is an *increasing* function. Hence 
$$3^{x^2}<3^{2x}\iff x^2<2x\iff x^2-2x=x(x-2)<0\iff 0<x<2.$$

Answer (score 0):

$3^{x^2}<9^x \iff$

$3^{x^2}<3^{2x} \iff$

$x^2<2x \iff$

$x(x-2)<0 \iff$

$0<x<2$.

Answer (score -1):

Use the laws of exponents.

That is, the corresponding equation is  $3^{(x^2)}=3^{(2x)}$; $x^2=2x$.

The rest follows trivially.

Comment: This is false. (Try $x = 1$)

Comment: @GFauxPas: Alephnull perhaps should have indicated that they were looking at roots of the equation, which would permit the OP to look only at representative values between and outside those roots—such as, for instance, $x = 1$.  At any rate, this answer does help toward that approach.

Comment: It frustrates me but ${3^x}^2$ is taken to mean $3^{(x^2)}$ which does not equal $(3^x)^2 = 3^{2x}$.  powers of powers is not associative so $(a^b)^c \ne a^{(b^c)}$.  I always have a hard time remembering which is the default interpretation but as $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$ can be expressed without parenthesis ${a^b}^c = a^{(b^c)}$ which can not other wise be expressed without parenthesis.

Comment: Oh, never mind.

Comment: I'm not sure he the rest "follows trivially" $3^{x^2} = 3^{2x} \implies x = 3$ but how do we determine when $3^{x^2} < 3^{2x}$ is it when x > 2 or when x < 2?

Comment: @fleablood you check it by a trivial calculation.

Comment: Oh... i guess on can do that.  *blush*  But you have to assume a^x = a^y iff x = y, and that a^x is continuous and the intermediate value theorem is known.

Comment: @fleablood Its a damn parabola. Just look at it.

Comment: @fleablood sorry if I'm wasting your time, but I used logarithms instead of all that. I reduced the precalculus problem to an algebra I problem.